# htaccess redirect subdomain to php file with get

Tags: .htaccess

How can i redirect subdomain to php file with $_GET using htaccess?

For example

```
en.domain.com => domain.com/index.php?lang=en
```

Comment: Please do not delete questions after they have been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put these directives into your **.htaccess** in a root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =en.domain.com
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/index.php?lang=en [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This rule will redirect (301, Permanent Redirect) from ANY URL at `en.domain.com` subdomain to this URL: `http://domain.com/index.php?lang=en` -- that's exactly what you have asked.

---

**UPDATE:**
This rule will take subdomain and pass it as a `lang` parameter to index.php. Right now rule supports 2 language: **en** (English) or **fr** (French). Edit this fragment (`en|fr`) to add/change languages.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(en|fr)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/index.php?lang=%1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

---

This rule will redirect from **ANY** subdomain (can be anything, even `jhjaghj77.domain.com`). I do not know how many languages you going to have .. but I would recommend the use previous option (when you specify all possible languages manually).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/index.php?lang=%1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but what of I have multiple languages? How can i make this more universal, so it'll redirect any word which will be entered instead EN to domain.com/index.php?lang=ANYTHING. I'll check if the language "exists" within the php file by myself.

Comment: @ytcax24433 I have updated my answer with more universal rule (2 variants -- I recommend first one).

Answer (score -1):

this code works when mod_rewrite is enabled on appache.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^.*\.domain.com$ domain.com/index.phph?lang=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does NOT work like that: check the manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/